# remove inside url some element via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Via an htaccess, I want to remove this point inside url  : Products/Description
example : https://test.com/Products/Description/logitech/Id-12

I tried this but it does not work.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Products/Description/$1$2 [L]
```

below is my complete htaccess tried rules file:

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectorySlash Off

# Remove WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

# Remove Trailing Slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)//+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]

# Reroute to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]


# Remove Products/Description ===> not working
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Products/Description/$1$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples and efforts, please try following .htaccess rules file. We need to do few changes in it. Make sure that your .htaccess file is residing along with `Products` folder(not inside it, besides it).

Also make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteBase /Products/Description/

DirectorySlash Off

# Remove WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]

# Remove Trailing Slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)//+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php\?([^&]*)&([^&]*)&Id=(\d+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(Products)/(Description)/(\d+)/?$ index.php?$1&$2&Id=$3 [QSA,NC,L]

# Reroute to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you,  I follow your instructions but I have an internal error.

Comment: @Pierre, ok sample link `https://test.com/Products/Description/logitech/Id-12` should be served by which file and link in backend?

Comment: the original link is : https://test.com/index.php?Products&Description&Id=12

Comment: @Pierre, ok so you are hitting this link in browser? and you want it to become like which sample link?

Comment: yes exactly, That's I am trying to do

Comment: @Pierre, ok sure, thanks for confirming, I have edited the rules now. Kindly do refresh this answer page once and try my new rules and let me know how it goes.

Comment: no the result (twice and clear cache )is : https://test.com/Products/Description/canon-eos-5d/Id-8

Comment: @Pierre, ok please do let me know where is your htaccess existing? Path and where is your index.php file.

Comment: my htaccess is in root, and my index.php is in https://example.com/index.php or about server path is /home/mfvs8363/test.com/

Comment: @Pierre, ok sure, are you getting 404 error when you hit this link?

Comment: no I have this and work :  test.com/Products/Description/canon-eos-5d/Id-8 but Products/Description is always inside the link

Comment: @Pierre, ok sure, I have updated my htaccess file now, please do check it and let me know how it goes.

Comment: No not workd, same url for the description and when I come back to index I have this https://example.com/index.php/index.php

Comment: @Pierre, so when you are hitting https://test.com/index.php?Products&Description&Id=12 you are being redirected to https://example.com/index.php/index.php in browser??

Comment: no I am redirected to http://test.com/Products/Description/canon-eos-5d/Id-12 is equivalent at https://test.com/index.php?Products&Description&Id=12.

Comment: @Pierre, yes, that's what I was trying to do, redirect to this link http://test.com/Products/Description/canon-eos-5d/Id-12  but backend serve it with index.php file only